# In kivy, how do I separate the on_release of multiple buttons in a single custom widget?

Tags: python, kivy, widget, kivy-language

I am defining a custom widget with multiple buttons named SplitButton in my kv file. I can hard code a function or call to a function in the on_release of each button *inside* the declaration of the custom widget. But what I am trying to do is access each button's individual on_release *outside* of its declaration, so that once I place the SplitButton onto the root widget, I can actually pass a written function into either button's on_release.

For example: Let's say the widget contains a left button and a right button. Instead of accessing on_release, perhaps there is a way I can access something named lb_on_release and rb_on_release? Hopefully, this abbreviated code will show the objective.

```
'''
<SplitButton>:
    Button:
        text: root.lb_text
        on_release: root.lb_on_release() # What should go here?
    Button:
        text: root.rb_text
        on_release: rb_on_release() # What should go here?

<Container>:
    SplitButton:
        rb_text: 'Right button'
        lb_text: 'Left button'
        rb_on_release: print('Right button has been pressed') # What I am trying to do
        lb_on_release: root.print_something() # What I am trying to do
'''

class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SplitButton(BoxLayout):
    lb_text = StringProperty('')
    rb_text = StringProperty('')
    # What do I do for lb_on_release and rb_on_release?

    def print_something(self):
        print('Left button has been pressed')
```

I've already been able to do that with the properties so that I can change each button's size_hint, background_color, text, etc. outside of its declaration. I'm only having issues with this. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a very similar thing with the `on_release` methods as you did with the `text`. You can add `ObjectProperty` in `SplitButton` to hold a reference to the method to be called in `on_release`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
'''
<SplitButton>:
    Button:
        text: root.lb_text
        on_release: root.lb_on_release()  # the () means actually call the indicated method
    Button:
        text: root.rb_text
        on_release: root.rb_on_release()

<Container>:
    SplitButton:
        rb_text: 'Right button'
        lb_text: 'Left button'
        rb_on_release: root.print_something  # this just sets rb_on_release to refer to the root.print_something method
        lb_on_release: self.print_something
'''

class Container(BoxLayout):
    def print_something(self, *args):
        print('root.print_something')

class SplitButton(BoxLayout):
    lb_text = StringProperty('')
    rb_text = StringProperty('')
    rb_on_release = ObjectProperty()  # ObjectProperty to hold reference to the method that should be called on release
    lb_on_release = ObjectProperty()

    def print_something(self):
        print('Left button has been pressed')
```

In fact, you don't even need to explicitly create the `ObjectProperty` in your python code, because kivy will create it for you based on the `kv` code.

Comment: I've actually tried that multiple times as well as exactly how you've shown me. I have 
lb_on_press and rb_on_press both with code in them in the kv file, but always get
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Not sure how to fix it. I have 
kivy 2.1.0 and python 3.9.13

Comment: Note very carefully where you do or do not have `()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see now. I must use parentheses ONLY in the declaration, but not outside the declaration to call a function. I got that to work. But I want on_lb_release to behave like on_release. I can't put a "print('something here') in it or I still get that NoneType error. I also cannot pass any data to root.print_something without getting the error. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `partial` method. For example, your `print('Right button has been pressed')` can be achieved by using `partial(print, 'Right button has been pressed')` in your `kv`. You must add `#: import partial functools.partial` at the top of yur `kv`.

Comment: Thank you again!!! These were exactly what I was looking for!!! I looked for days with no luck on the function part. Issues solved.